# The requested resource is not available. Spring RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I get an error that says "The requested resource is not available", although it seems like all the RequestMappings are OK. Could you help me understand and solve the problem?

The controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping
    public String list(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("products", productService.getAllProducts());

        return "products";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public String allProducts(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("products", productService.getAllProducts());

        return "products";
    }
}
```

It works OK if I type //webstore/products. The view is resolved correctly and the page is displayed.

But If I type //webstore/products/all and error occurs: "The requested resource is not available".

The path seems to be erroneous: /webstore/products/WEB-INF/views/products.jsp

I think it should be: /webstore/WEB-INF/views/products.jsp

Comment: Can you show us your web.xml and spring configuration if any?

Comment: @nebula Sure. web.xml http://codepaste.net/5b22d5 Spring context: http://codepaste.net/fgrwau

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the DispatcherServlet-context.xml configuration file. The InternalResourceVierResolver was:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

whereas it should be:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

The difference is in the property name value.